# SQL changing types

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

hi if i have the following :

table x {

```
 num1 double precision;
 num2 int;
```

}

and now i want to find out num2/num1  and round to 1 decimal place.

is there a way to do this in a SELECT query? for the double precision.. do i have to use numeric(4,1) or something like that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`round()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-math.html#FUNCTIONS-MATH-FUNC-TABLE):

```
SELECT ROUND(num2/num1, 1) FROM x;
```

PostgreSQL will automatically upgrade the division to floating point when `num1` is floating point:

```
> select 3/3.145927;
        ?column?        
------------------------
 0.95361399040727899916
(1 row)
```

And:

```
> select round(3/3.145927, 1);
 round 
-------
   1.0
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on mu's answer... Depending on your postgres version, you might need to add an explicit cast, because round(numeric, int) exists but round(float, int) does not:

```
select round(num1::numeric/num2::numeric, 1);
```